# In terms of levels and gamification what would be the best option between infinite points and scaled levels?

Tags: gamification, progress

### **Infinite points** or **Scaled levels**

I'm wondering what would be the best option UX-wise in terms of user levels and gamification for a contribution app :

Are the users more sensible about a goal that would not be visible (like in Stack exchange, there is no final level, only points till' infinity) or are they more sensible about achieving levels over levels?

I would say that the first option, `Infinite points` would be simpler to implement and would be understandable for everyone.

But I'm concerned about this "getting rewards on a regular basis" option `Scaled levels`.

What would be your point on an issue like this one, UX-wise?

Comment: Ask your users. Either ask them before you decide, or just pick one, implement it, and then get user feedback later. Also, SE does have "levels" so to speak, they are called ["privileges"](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)

Answer (score 1):

Only going for points (or levels) might not be enough. SE does multiple things:

- infinite points
- earned privileges (which actually give you more permissions)
- compare the the points to others there is a quite clever ranking system which ranks you overall or in the last month etc.

So having said so. I think you should probably give more then just points, let users 'compete'. This can be done by a ranking or similar.

To your question: It depends what you want to achieve

If you want your users to stay tuned an contribute right away another thing a scaled level system might be the better option since it is a motivation to gain another level.

If you don't whant to push the user to make another contribution right away but reward them when coming back an contribute again just giving infinite points might be better.

I see it a little bit like this: Levels might be better for quantitative contributions and infinite points for qualitative contributions. This is just an assumption that would have to be proofed.